# Replacing Strings in php

Tags: php, regex

Considering the following input HTML:

```
<div class='content'>
    <img style='border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;' src='/media/uploads/defaults/181'/><br/><br/>
    <div class='imgCaption'>
        Reverse Osmosis Caption
    </div>
</div>
<pagebreak/>
<h3>Access </h3>
<h4>Type</h4>
<div class='content'>
    Your plumbing system is accessible with a Main Shut off Valves
</div>
<h4>Location</h4>
<pagebreak/>
<h3>Operation & maintenance #1</h3>
<div class='content'>
    All wastewater treatment systems and their components require regular maintenance.
</div>
<h4>Activity</h4>
```

So I need to find all h4 headers that are not followed by the div of class "content". (In this example, it's "h4 Activity /h4" at the very bottom).

My regex

```
/<h4>.*<\/h4>(?!<div class='content'>)/
```

captures everything after

```
<h4>Type</h4>
```

Which makes sense since it's followed by not just "div class='content'".

So my question is how I can re-write the query so it only picks up the headers that are not followed by div of class content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `.*?` at the first inside the [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). If you fail to add `.*?`, negative lookahead will check for the immediate following of `<div class='content'>` tag.

```
<h4>(?:(?!<\/?h4>).)*?<\/h4>(?!.*?<div class='content'>)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xC7bJ2/3)

It will match the last `h4` tag because it isn't followed by any `<div class='content'>` tag.